# Trying to create a stacked bar chart, but cannot drag "Measure Names" to Color

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm a first time user and every tutorial starts off with this step.  My data looks like

| dept | sold | unsold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 6 |
| B | 8 | 9 |

I am using the free trial on their website if that makes a difference

Comment: Hi, can you please sign-up on https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/   and publish your work there, share the link . I will try to debug from there itself. Also share more details, like what you are exactly trying to visualize